# jquery mobile load external page, events not getting triggered

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-pageshow

I want to transition to an external jquery mobile page, but none event is getting trigger, when the transition is called:

```
jQuery("#test1").on("pagebeforeshow", function(event) {
            WL.Logger.debug("pagebeforeshow: test1");
        });

function loadHTML(){
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("load", "./pages/test1/test1.html", {});

    }
    function openHTML(){
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "./pages/test1/test1.html", {});
    }
```

and this is the content on my HTML :

```
<div data-role="page" id="test1">
    <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px"></div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to use any event?

Comment: did you try jQuery(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#test1" function(event) {...?  This is event delegation which allows for the test1 to not exist when the handler is created.

Comment: that solve my problem, thx, can you change your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To attach the pagebeforeshow handler to a page not loaded into the DOM yet, you must use event delegation:

https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

```
jQuery(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#test1" function(event) {...
```